# Auto fill from search result with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Hi I have the below code that populate a search result with user-id, User_mname, email

I want to auto fill a field with id= id with the appropriate Id user click on

```
    <?php 

    include '../db/connect6.php';


if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
  $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oz2ts_users WHERE oz2ts_users.id LIKE  '%$searchq%' OR oz2ts_users.name LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not  search"); 
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
     $output = 'There is no result to show!'; 
    } else{ 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $username = $row['username'];    

    $output .= '<div><a class="resultItem" data-id="' . $id . '">'   
     . $name . ' '.$username.'</a></div>';   

   }            
 }

 }
echo($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do an .onclick() event that targets the field.  Sample code below.

```
<form>
   <input id="display-id" type="text" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.resultItem').click(function(){
         var resultId = $(this).data('id');
         $('#display-id').val(resultId);
    });    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I tried that but it doesn't work. I am having the error `TypeError: $(...).onclick is not a function` probably from `    $('.resultItem').onclick(function(){`  Error shows when the form loads and click does nothing

Comment: Oops, must have been asleep when I did this.  I edited the code above to correct it.  In short, "onclick" (as I previously had) is pure javascript, but ".click()" (as I have now) is the jQuery way :D